# ForEach line of a list get the string, search for specific node in XML and delete the parent node using Powershell

Tags: xml, list, powershell, xpath, foreach

I have a list with strings which for each line there is a correspondent node in a XML file. All the parents need to be deleted in that XML.
The script is roughly working but the result is not correct. And I'm getting some errors with the variable `$line` inside a Xpath query.
I'm struggling to figure out what is happening with that variable.

**romlist.txt:**

```
1941.zip
llander.zip
warrior.zip
```

**gamelist.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <gameList>
      <game id="46415" source="screenscraper.fr">
          <path>.aaa/bbb/warrior.zip</path>
          <name>Warrior</name>
          <desc>qweqwe</desc>
          <image>./images/warrior-image.png</image>
          <rating>0.7</rating>
          <releasedate>19790101T000000</releasedate>
          <developer>Tim Skelly</developer>
          <publisher>Vectorbeam</publisher>
          <genre>Fight / N/A</genre>
          <players>2</players>
          <video>./videos/warrior-video.mp4</video>
      </game>
      <game id="39873" source="screenscraper.fr">
          <path>.ccc/ddd/1941.zip</path>
          <name>1941 - Counter Attack</name>
          <desc>asdasd</desc>
          <image>./images/1941-image.png</image>
          <rating>0.8</rating>
          <releasedate>19900101T000000</releasedate>
          <developer>Capcom</developer>
          <publisher>Capcom</publisher>
          <genre>Shoot'em up / Vertical / Shoot'em Up</genre>
          <players>2</players>
          <video>./videos/1941-video.mp4</video>
      </game>
      <game id="46408" source="screenscraper.fr">
          <path>.eee/fff/sundance.zip</path>
          <name>Sundance</name>
          <desc>zxczxc</desc>
          <image>./images/sundance-image.png</image>
          <rating>0.5</rating>
          <releasedate>19790101T000000</releasedate>
          <developer>Tim Skelly</developer>
          <publisher>Cinematronics</publisher>
          <genre>N/A / Various</genre>
          <players>2</players>
          <video>./videos/sundance-video.mp4</video>
      </game>
      <game id="46393" source="screenscraper.fr">
          <path>.ggg/hhh/llander.zip</path>
          <name>Lunar Lander</name>
          <desc>asdasd</desc>
          <image>./images/llander-image.png</image>
          <rating>0.9</rating>
          <releasedate>19790101T000000</releasedate>
          <developer>Atari</developer>
          <publisher>Atari</publisher>
          <genre>Various / N/A / Simulation</genre>
          <players>1</players>
          <video>./videos/llander-video.mp4</video>
      </game>
  </gameList>
```

**POWERSHELL:**

```
$input = "gamelist.xml"
$output = "gamelist_result.xml"
$romlist = "romlist.txt"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $input -Raw

ForEach($line in Get-Content $romlist) {
    $rom = $xml.selectSingleNode('//game/path[contains(text(),line)]') | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
    ForEach($node in $xml.gameList.game | Where-Object {$_.path -eq $rom})
    {
    $xml.gameList.RemoveChild($node)
    }
}

$path = (join-path $pwd $output)
$xml.Save($path)
```

If `$xml.selectSingleNode('//game/path[contains(text(),line)]')` we have no errors but the result is wrong.

If `$xml.selectSingleNode('//game/path[contains(text(),$line)]')` we have some errors and the result is inverted, where the list is preserved instead of being deleted.

I'd appreciate any help to fixing this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood you.

```
$rom, $inp = 'C:\path\romlist.txt', 'C:\path\gamelist.xml'
($lst, $xml = (Get-Content $rom), [xml](Get-Content $inp))[0].ForEach{
   $nod = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//path[contains(text(), '$_')]")
   [void]$xml.gameList.RemoveChild($nod.ParentNode)
}
$xml.Save('C:\path\gamelist_result.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks @greg zakharov, beautiful coding with good performance.
Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct but there's a problem in this line:

```
$xml.selectSingleNode('//game/path[contains(text(),line)]')
```

If you want Powershell to replace `line` for its value then use external double quotation marks and `$`. Also need to add literal single quotation marks around `$line` because the function `contains` is expecting them for delimiting the value.

```
$xml.selectSingleNode("//game/path[contains(text(),'$line')]")
```

With that change it should work. However I have refactored the rest a bit to make it more concise.

```
ForEach($line in Get-Content $romlist) {
    $rom = $xml.selectSingleNode("//game/path[contains(text(),'$line')]") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
    $xml.gameList.ChildNodes | Where-Object{ $_.path -eq $rom } | ForEach-Object { $xml.gameList.RemoveChild($_) } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @derloopkat for helping me with your nice explanation. It works perfectly.